# Deleting an item if it intersects between the two ObservableCollection datatypes

Tags: c#, silverlight, list

How can I delete items if they intersections between two Observable-collection sources.

Comment: What do you mean?  How do *two* ObservableCollections relate to one list?

Comment: @Eric J. Yes. The recent files can hold a filename that does not exist in the the global files list(because it was deleted). So when deleting an item from the global list, i dont want it to appear in the recent files.

Comment: @asdgfassagas Put more information with example.

Answer (score 0):

Use Linq, unless you are dealing with very large sets; but I'm assuming not since these are observable collections.

Given

```
ObservableCollection<T> set1, ObservableCollection<T> set2
```

get the intersection as:

```
var intersection = set1.Intersect(set2);
```

Use a custom equality comparer if and as necessary.

Comment: I used something like this `RecentPatients.Where(x => Patients.Contains(x)).ToObservableCollection();    `

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach(var p in recentPatients.Intersect(patients).ToList())
    recentPatients.Remove(p);
```

Comment: I was under the impression that deleting an element while still inside the loop can produce an exception. Can you explain why this doesn't occur?